# xSCOM 1.3.3.0 throws an Exception when running DSC on Azure VM

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-powershell, dsc

All,

I am trying to automate infrastructure where I am using Azure DevOps CI / CD Pipeline for deploying VM and using DSC to configure / install SCOM using Module XSCOM 1.3.3.0. As per my colleague, the below code works on a VMWare VM.

**Question:**
Any idea on the below error or any other method of installing SCOM on an Azure machine in an automated fashion?

**DSC Code:**

```
xSCOMManagementServerSetup "OMMS"
{
  DependsOn         = @('[Package]ODBCDriver13', '[Package]SQLClient11')
         Ensure     = "Present"
          SourcePath        = $SCM2016Path
          SetupCredential   = $AdminCreds
          #ProductKey       = $Node.SCM2016Key
          ManagementGroupName   = $MgmtGrp
          InstallPath       = $SCM2016InstallPath
          FirstManagementServer = $false
          ActionAccount     = $OpsActionCredential
          DASAccount        = $OpsSDKCredential
          DataReader        = $OpsDRACredential
          DataWriter        = $OpsDWACredential
          SqlServerInstance     = $SCM2016DB
          DatabaseSize      = $DatabaseSize
          DwSqlServerInstance   = $SCM2016DWDB
          DWDatabaseSize    = $DWDatabaseSize
 # UseMicrosoftUpdate   = 
        }

xSCOMWebConsoleServerSetup "OMWC"
        {
          DependsOn             = '[xSCOMManagementServerSetup]OMMS'
          Ensure            = "Present"
          SourcePath            = $SCM2016Path
          SetupCredential       = $AdminCreds
  InstallPath           = $SCM2016InstallPath
          ManagementServer      = $nodename
  WebSiteName           = "Default Web Site"
  WebConsoleAuthorizationMode   = "Mixed"
  WebConsoleUseSSL      = $false
    }

xSCOMConsoleSetup "OMC"
    {
         DependsOn      = '[xSCOMWebConsoleServerSetup]OMWC'
          Ensure        = "Present"
          SourcePath        = $SCM2016Path
  InstallPath       = $SCM2016InstallPath
          SetupCredential   = $AdminCreds
      }
```

**Error:**

```
Job {94883009-5CFE-11EC-A811-002248041883} :
Message Set-TargetResouce failed
HResult -2146233087
StackTrack    at System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.PipelineBase.Invoke(IEnumerable input)
   at System.Management.Automation.PowerShell.Worker.ConstructPipelineAndDoWork(Runspace rs, Boolean performSyncInvoke)
   at System.Management.Automation.PowerShell.Worker.CreateRunspaceIfNeededAndDoWork(Runspace rsToUse, Boolean isSync)
   at System.Management.Automation.PowerShell.CoreInvokeHelper[TInput,TOutput](PSDataCollection`1 input, PSDataCollection`1 output, PSInvocationSettings settings)
   at System.Management.Automation.PowerShell.CoreInvoke[TInput,TOutput](PSDataCollection`1 input, PSDataCollection`1 output, PSInvocationSettings settings)
   at System.Management.Automation.PowerShell.Invoke(IEnumerable input, PSInvocationSettings settings)
   at Microsoft.PowerShell.DesiredStateConfiguration.Internal.ResourceProviderAdapter.ExecuteCommand(PowerShell powerShell, ResourceModuleInfo resInfo, String operationCmd, List`1 acceptedProperties, CimInstance nonResourcePropeties, CimInstance resourceConfiguration, LCMDebugMode debugMode, PSInvocationSettings pSInvocationSettings, UInt32& resultStatusHandle, Collection`1& result, ErrorRecord& errorRecord, PSModuleInfo localRunSpaceModuleInfo)
```

Answer (score 0):

All System Center Operations Manager (SCOM) individual management group deployments will either be an "all-in-one" installation, where all features are loaded on a single server, or a distributed installation. [Deploying System Center Operations Manager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/system-center/scom/deploy-overview?view=sc-om-2019) describes more about the same.

The **Install-SCOMAgent** cmdlet deploys one or more System Center 2019 - Operations Manager and later product version agents by using client push installation. The code snippet below shows the syntax.

```
Install-SCOMAgent
       [-ActionAccount <PSCredential>]
       [-AgentActionAccount <PSCredential>]
       -DNSHostName <String[]>
       -PrimaryManagementServer <ManagementServer>
       [-NoAPM]
       [-PassThru]
       [-WhatIf]
       [-Confirm]
       [<CommonParameters>]
```

Check [Install-SCOMAgent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/operationsmanager/install-scomagent?view=systemcenter-ps-2019) document for examples. Also check [Setup and configure Log Analytics using SCOM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/services-hub/health/setup-config-log-analytics-scom).

But as far as I know there is no way of installing the SCOM management server role without first uninstalling the Log Analytics/Azure Monitoring agent. You should be able to connect your server by using the SCOM agent to connect to the Log Analytics Workspace afterwards, check **[Connect Operations Manager to Azure Monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/agents/om-agents)** for more information.

Also check this [Automate SCOM 2016 installation with PowerShell](https://rlevchenko.com/2018/01/16/automate-scom-2016-installation-with-powershell/) to automate the installation of SCOM on azure virtual machine (Windows Server 2016).